# Dropdown Menu (Select Plugin) Gets Cut Off In React Table

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using these 2 plugins [React Select v2](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#readme) and [react table v6](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table#readme) the dropdown on the last row of react-table is activated the "menu" is hidden underneath react-table so you actually dont see it.

All my code is boiler plate(no extra styling) and since it gets rendered to html anyways I don't see much point to post the code up.

Anyone else run into this same issue?